# Disabling WMM causes Wi-Fi Speeds to drop to 14Mbps

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bandwidth, qos

So due to certain problems with my Android Device I decided to disable WMM in my router settings (which fixes the problem)

But after disabled the total speed of the Wi-Fi is reduced to a extremely low 14Mbps on all devices on my network.
Also this is not 14Mbps on each device, it is a total throughput of 14Mbps meaning that if multiple devices are using the network simultaneously the speed of 14Mbps is divided between them.

Does anyone have any idea why the speed is limited so low.

Note : The speed test was done using iperf3 between two wireless devices and wired and wireless device. So my internet speed doesn't come into the factor.
I have also tried changing the wireless mode to 802.11N only which doesn't help improve the situation.
I have tested the speed of the Wi-Fi and it reaches upto 80Mbps or download or upload and 60Mbps of both download and upload simultaneously

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wireless Multimedia Extensions (WMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions)
is the default setting of most modems and should be left enabled.

While WMM is, indeed, designed to give priority to multimedia traffic, it is also required in order to use the high throughput link rates.  When WMM is disabled, only 54 Mbps is possible.

WMM is required by 802.11n and 802.11ac for link speeds above 54 Mbps, so disabling it
can affect your overall Internet speed. If your Internet speed is 20 Mbps or less,
then you maybe could get away with disabling WMM, but WiFi is going to be terrible.
You could also try playing around with Dynamic QoS, if supported by the router.
Dynamic QoS works on top of WMM and may be able to re-prioritize your gaming traffic.

I suggest finding a better solution than disabling WMM.
If your phone has difficulties with it, find other ways of dealing with the problem.

Comment: Problem is that it isn't even crossing 14Mbps with WMM disabled. My internet runs at 40Mbps.

Comment: You need WMM for fast WiFi. You need to find a solution to the problem that doesn't require disabling WMM.